# Is it possible to use an array in the values part of a mysql query using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use an array of some sort in the below type of mysql query using PHP?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table_name ($table_columns) VALUES($my_array)";
```

The situation:
I'm creating a library/package that will allow users to upload csv file data into a mysql database table in laravel.

The library/package will allow the user to enter the table name required and upload the csv file of thier choice.

The reason an array would be best suited for the VALUE field is because it will resolve the need for the VALUE parameters to be typed/updated manually (as depending on the table column count the CSV line paramter count could be any number in question).

Comment: I think not, as it has no idea how to translate array to string... why would you do that instead of using Query Builder or a Model ?

Comment: If you use an ORM the answer might be yes. If you're banging out raw queries, no.

Comment: @Krayz we are not wrong, you were smashing an array in a string, of corse you have to use a native PHP function for making it work... I do not have 10 years experience and do not know the answer for this simple question...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Reading my question again I think I could have articulated it a bit better (after reading your new response)! However, it seems that John was able to undertsand what I was trying to express. Just to be clear, the reason why I'm not using a model etc is because I'm working with csv data. I'm sending the csv line data here there and everywhere for processing and most important the line can can contain any number of elements. I didn't mean to be rude or offend you. Honestly, just wanted to update you.

Comment: @Krayz If by "works" you mean "has an extremely hazardous SQL injection bug" then sure. This is **not** how to do it. This is how you become a liability to whatever project you are working on. Escaping and injecting is better than just injecting, but it's still vulnerable. Use placeholder values. It's not hard.

Comment: PDO has much better binding systems than `mysqli`, you can more easily bind against an arbitrary array. With `mysqli` you can do it, but it's ugly.

Comment: @tadman After researching sql injections and the use of place holder values I now realise how much of an issue it is not being aware of the vunerabilties. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. This is a lot more important than people realize. Look at what a simple [tool like this can do](https://sqlmap.org) and remember, it only takes one tiny hole for all those things to be possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes. This can be possible. As you know the syntax of INSERT query is:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'ABC');
```

So you can use the implode function to INSERT data into MySQL using array.

```
$table_name = "users";
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: Thank you John Doe :)   Works like a charm. 

Just a few minor points for anyone that needs to copy this code word for word:

$values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);  //needed to add ' to both sides of the comma

...and 

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name ($columns) VALUES ('$values')";   // needed to add ' to both sides of $value